# Writing data into file using java in code competition

Tags: java

While practicing the previous year google code jam problems, the system gives incorrect , even though the solution is correct. I have encountered it twice. My solution is correct when I checked with the other programmers solution that is available. Both produces same output.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String three;
        int i=1;
        try
        {
             File input=new File("input.txt");
             File output=new File("output.txt");
             FileWriter file=new FileWriter(output);
             original=3+(Math.sqrt(5));
             Scanner scan=new Scanner(input);
             number=scan.nextInt();
             BufferedWriter buff=new BufferedWriter(file);
             while(scan.hasNext())
             {      
                 buff.write("Case #"+i+": ");
                 number=scan.nextInt();
                 value=Math.pow(original, number);
                 threedigit=((int)value)%1000;
                 if(threedigit<100)
                 {
                     three= "0"+ (Integer.toString(threedigit));
                    // write.write(Integer.parseInt(three));
                    // threedigit=Integer.parseInt(three);
                     buff.write(three);             System.out.println(three);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     three=Integer.toString(threedigit);
                     System.out.println(three);
                     threedigit=Integer.parseInt(three);
                     buff.write(three);
                 }
                 i++;
                 buff.newLine();

             }
             buff.close();

         }
```

output:

```
Case #1: 935
Case #2: 471
Case #3: 903
Case #4: 751
Case #5: 027
Case #6: 647
Case #7: 647
Case #8: 647
Case #9: 647
Case #10: 607
Case #11: 647
Case #12: 647
Case #13: 991
Case #14: 143
Case #15: 047
Case #16: 647
Case #17: 647
Case #18: 647
Case #19: 647
Case #20: 647
Case #21: 647
Case #22: 647
Case #23: 647
Case #24: 647
Case #25: 943
Case #26: 647
Case #27: 647
Case #28: 647
Case #29: 335
```

other programmer's program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class p3small {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // This was generated using the unix calculator bc, using the script generated by the 
        // other java code (and scale = 100), the results manually copied here.
        String sol[] = {"027", "143", "751", "935", "607", "903", "991", "335", "047", "943", "471", "055", "447", "463", 
            "991","095","607", "263", "151", "855", "527", "743", "351", "135", "407", "903", "791", "135", "647"};

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("p3.in"));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("p3.out");
        for (int i=0; i<t; i++) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String res = sol[n-2];
            out.write("Case #" + (i+1) + ": " + res + "\n");
        }
        out.close();
        br.close();

    }
}
```

I know I am making some mistake in writing into the file.
Please help me, It demotivates me to practice.

Comment: format your post please, and please when you are done with formatting your post, please post your stack trace to give everyone better idea what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I would check that your maths is correct. I strongly suspect you are getting an overflow as Math.pow could be a large number, too large to store in an `int` value.

Comment: Most of these sort of problems are actually maths problems, not programming problems. I.e. the maths trick you do should be hard bit and if it not, you have missed something.